# Loading data from a json file when an element is selected from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, json

Create an application to load districts from a JSON file hosted at the server and list the districts according to a selected province given in a dropdown box.
First, create a form with the followings.

- Suitable title
- A dropdown list containing all the provinces in Sri Lanka. (Use an
  array to store the provinces, the first element is "Please select"
  and the rest are provinces)
- A div to load districts

Initially, the dropdown list is selected as "Please select".
When you select a province from the dropdown list all the districts relevant to that province will be loaded and displayed in the div with bullets (Hint: `<ul><li></li></ul>`)
The list of districts should be in a JSON file with the relevant province name.

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Select a province</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="myselect" onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
                        <option value="1">Select province</option>
                        <option value="2">Western</option>



                    </select>
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>


    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function change_myselect(sel) {
  var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
  obj = { table: sel, limit: 20 };
  dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      txt += "<table border='1'>"
      for (x in myObj) {
        txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
      }
      txt += "</table>"    
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
      }
    };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "districts.json", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}
</script>



</body>

</html>
```

JSON FILE

```
{
    "province":"Western",
    "name":"Colombo",
    "name":"Gampaha",
    "name":"Kalutara"

}
```

I have tried creating a simple json file with the data that should be displayed when 'western' is selected from my drop down list. I am not getting any data when I run the code :(

I am getting this in my table

```
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: What are you getting in `this.responseText`?

Comment: I am new to this subject and have no idea about it....please help me... I have doubts about the way in which my data in json file should be organized

Comment: you can debug it in any modern browser, just select developer tools->debugger. add a break point. you can step through the code and verify the values/ see the errors etc.

Comment: Why `PHP` is tagged here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your json into following format :

```
{ 
    "provinces" :[
    { "province":"Western", "name":"Colombo" },
    { "province":"Western", "name":"Gampaha" },
    { "province":"Western", "name":"Kalutara"}
    ]
}
```

You can validate your json with an online service such as https://jsonlint.com/

And your loop as follows :

```
 for (x in myObj.provinces) {
    txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj.provinces[x].name + "</td></tr>";
  }
```

Comment: If i want to add more elements in the drop down list, how can i change my json file and for loop accordingly?

Comment: <select id="myselect" onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select province</option>
      <option value="1">North</option>
      <option value="2">North Western</option>
      <option value="3">North Central</option>
      <option value="4">Eastern</option>
      <option value="5">Western</option>
      <option value="6">Sabaragamuwa</option>
      <option value="7">Uva</option>
      <option value="8">Southern</option>
      <option value="9">Wayamba</option>
      
     </select>

Comment: You could add any item between square brackets as { "province" : "Northern", "name" : "Whatever"}. No need to change for loop. Maybe you could add an if block to filter only selected province values.

Comment: I tried to add two more elements to the drop down box and more districts for each province in the json file like you mentioned...but again I'm not getting any output as display

Comment: <select id="myselect" onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select province</option>
      <option value="1">North</option>
      <option value="2">Western</option>
      <option value="3">Southern</option>
      
     </select>

Comment: "provinces" :[
 { "province":"North", "name":"Kilinochchi"},
 { "province":"North", "name":"Mulativu"},
 { "province":"North", "name":"Wavuniya"},
 { "province":"North", "name":"Mannar"},
 { "province":"North", "name":"Jaffna"},
    { "province":"Western", "name":"Colombo" },
    { "province":"Western", "name":"Gampaha" },
    { "province":"Western", "name":"Kalutara"},
 { "province":"Southern", "name":"Galle"},
 { "province":"Southern", "name":"Hambantota"},
 { "province":"Southern", "name":"Matara"}

Comment: I made a simple plunker project. You can view the working sample there : https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ptcw1L4NDUmrG1ND. Used a switch statement and an if statement to filter out selected province elements.

Answer (score 0):

Replae below Code use `x.name` instead of `myObj[x].name`

```
function change_myselect(sel) {
  var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
  obj = { table: sel, limit: 20 };
  dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      txt += "<table border='1'>"
      for (x in myObj) {
        txt += "<tr><td>" + x.name + "</td></tr>";
      }
      txt += "</table>"    
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
      }
    };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "districts.json", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}
```

JSON File must be like

```
[{
    "name":"Colombo"  
},
{
"name":"Gampaha"
}]
```

Comment: i changed the code to  x.name instead of myObj[x].name.But still im not getting the data in the table....maybe the format of the data in the json file is not correct?? @ Vaibhavi Sojitra

Comment: @VinuriMithara Try to check by  Console(myObj). and add result in your comment what will you get ??

Comment: Still not working...i changed the json file format too

Comment: @VinuriMithara What is your console.log(myObj) response ?? `myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); console.log(myObj);`

Comment: how can i check this above part?through the browser?

Comment: yes, right click -> inspect element -> show in console. @VinuriMithara